# How do I attach a physical DVD to a Hyper-V machine?

Tags: virtualization, dvd, hyper-v, windows-installation

I have Hyper-V running on Windows 8.1 host and now I need to install an operating system on the virtual machine.  My operating system is on a physical DVD in a USB DVD drive attached to the physical computer.

How can I attach this DVD to the Hyper-V virtual machine for system installation?

Comment: attach the usb device to the virtual machine or virtually mount the diskby keeping the usb device visible to the host machine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generation 2 virtual machines don't support booting from physical DVDs.  Either use a Generation 1 VM, or use a virtual DVD (an ISO).

The [same question and answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/564990/guest-os-install-from-physical-cd-dvd-hyper-v-2012-r2) is over at Server Fault.  (Not sure if this qualifies as a duplicate when on different sites).